# I have a Google Apps script set up to automatically archive old emails. It used to work, but now I get an authorization error

Tags: google-apps-script

This is the script:

```
function gmailAutoarchive() {
  var delayDays = 3; // will only impact emails more than this many days old

  // Get all the threads that are old. Leave alone read, importnat, and starred emails.
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:inbox label:unread -in:important -in:starred older_than:" + delayDays + "d");
  
  // we archive all the threads
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].moveToArchive();
  }
}
```

And this is the error I get sent to me in an email every so often:

[image]

I clicked the documentation link, but it's not very helpful; just an index of documentation for Google Apps Script, and if I search for "authorization", none of the links are very helpful either... how do I authorize my script?

Comment: In your script, when you manually run the script with the script editor, what result will you obtain? For example, the authorization screen is opened?

Comment: It should ask for authorization the time you installed the trigger in the first place.

Comment: You say "every so often" - has it ever run successfully? If not, then as hinted at above, you can run your function manually by pressing the play button in the editor. This should automatically get an authorization UI pop up.

Comment: Yes, it did run in the past. Run it manually to authorize it? Good idea! Seems to be working so far, taking a while to run...